How do we reconcile the story of the woman caught in adultery in John 8 and the man stoned for picking up sticks on Sabbath in Numbers 15?
Jesus seems to say that only those without sin should cast a stone at the lawbreaker:
John 8 (NASB95):

3 The scribes and the Pharisees *brought a woman caught in adultery, and having set her in the center of the court,
4 they *said to Him, “Teacher, this woman has been caught in adultery, in the very act.
5 Now in the Law Moses commanded us to stone such women; what then do You say?”
6 They were saying this, testing Him, so that they might have grounds for accusing Him. But Jesus stooped down and with His finger wrote on the ground.
7 But when they persisted in asking Him, He straightened up, and said to them, “He who is without sin among you, let him be the first to throw a stone at her.”

But God says all the congregation should stone the lawbreaker to death:
Numbers 15:

32 Now while the sons of Israel were in the wilderness, they found a man gathering wood on the sabbath day.
33 Those who found him gathering wood brought him to Moses and Aaron and to all the congregation;
34 and they put him in custody because it had not been declared what should be done to him.
35 Then the Lord said to Moses, “The man shall surely be put to death; all the congregation shall stone him with stones outside the camp.”


Consider that Jesus is without a sin, so technically he himself should have thrown the first stone.
But after baptism he is not under Moses law jurisdiction so he doesn’t have to.

John 7:53-8:11 is considered a spurious text; see Origin of John 8:1-11.

@agarza - just worth noting (for the sake of balance) that it is considered by some to be spurious

Numbers 15 illustrates God's justice, John 8 his mercy. While these two attributes of God inevitably conflict when it comes to sin, they are reconciled through Christ.

Jesus was, indeed, without sin (unlike the woman's accusers who skulked away - the oldest first - after realising Jesus knew exactly what was going on with them regarding this particular episode.)
So, could Jesus have cast that first stone? No, because the Law stated that "At the mouth of two or three witnesses every matter shall be established."(Deuteronomy 19:15 & Matthew 18:16) There had to be at least two eye-witnesses whose testimony would not conflict. But Jesus had not been an eye-witness to this act of adultery.
Further, if both the woman and the man "had been caught in the very act", both of them should have been accused. Why was only the woman accused? Where was the guilty man? Why did the people who accused the woman bring her to Jesus, to ask Jesus about the matter? He had nothing to do with this. Were they out to trap Jesus (by using this woman)?
This shows that there is no comparison between that event and the other some 1,470 years earlier, where there were sufficient eye-witnesses to the choice of the man to break God's newly-given law, by gathering sticks that day. It was almost as if that man was thinking, "Pah! What a ridiculous law! I need sticks to cook today, even though God has also said no cooking is to be done this day." We may surmise that after he had been punished as the Law required, the Israelites who witnessed capital punishment being carried out would not dare break that Law themselves. But how many people throughout history have been deterred from crimes of passion that have the death penalty attached? It remains a fact that the Law of God in Israel required at least two sound eye-witnesses to adultery before anything could be done.
Now, we all know that if wicked people set up a trap to get someone accused, they are not sound eye-witnesses, and are law-breakers themselves. In this instance, they were out to trap Jesus. And he knew it. So, he answered in such a way as to turn the accusation on their heads, which also ensured that the woman could not be stoned to death, for no two eye-witnesses were left to accuse her. "Does no-one accuse you?" he asked, after being bent down to write on the ground. "Then neither do I. Go and sin no more."
The answer is that there is nothing to reconcile between the texts of the woman caught in the midst, and the man caught gathering sticks.

. . . .  then there is the evidence of what Jesus wrote on the ground, all around her, which they dare not trample on, in order to get to her. Then there is the fact that he is 'Lord'. Then there is the certainty that he will bear all her sins . . . . . .  himself, justly, righteously, they shall be judged, to the utmost, within his own body. Thus there is a reconciliation (apokattalasso) . . . .  within the Lord himself. Up-voted +1.

"But how many people throughout history have been deterred from crimes of passion that have the death penalty attached?"  It's difficult to read people's minds, of course, but we can extrapolate fairly well from the data: strong punishment mixed with a strong likelihood of getting caught and punished shows a very strong deterrent effect indeed! When such policies are in place, the crimes in question go down, and when they are weakened, crime goes up. When, in places like California in recent years, the deterrent is removed altogether, crime surges! So the answer to your question is "Plenty."

@MasonWheeler  Well, this Q deals with the death penalty in ancient Israel and that comment I made simply mentioned crimes of passion (such as adultery, in this case). Today sexual immorality has spread like a cancer throughout most of the world and nobody seems to think twice about it, with no criminality attached to it hardly anywhere. Some of the worst violators are religious leaders. "As it was in the days of Noah"... uh? But that's a change of topic, pardon me. I just wanted to acknowledge your comment, thanks.


Jesus seems to say that only those without sin should cast a stone at the lawbreaker:

Sort of.  Jesus was not saying that it was unlawful for anyone else to cast the first stone, nor was he denying the scribes' and Parisees' interpretation of the law. "'He who is without sin among you, let him be the first to throw a stone at her'" is not a command, for the scribes and Pharisees did not recognize Jesus's authority to command them.
The Pharisees were asking Jesus for a rabbinical opinion, hoping to either catch him in a heresy should he deny the provisions of the Law, or else to undercut his popular standing and perhaps get him in trouble with the Roman authorities should he endorse stoning the woman.  Jesus's response urges the crowd to consider whether they want to be held to the same standard that they propose to apply to the adultress.  Perhaps by Law she was deserving of death, but Jesus made the crowd confront the fact that so too were all of them.  He changed it from a matter of what the law says, to one of what the crowd was prepared to do about it.
As for Jesus himself, he had and has the power to forgive sin, which he exercised in this case ("neither do I condemn you", John 8:11).  The adulteress having been absolved of that sin, it would have been wrong to stone her for it.  This justified not only Jesus' inaction, but also the crowd's. To whatever extent the Law might have imposed an obligation on them to stone the woman, it no longer did once she was forgiven of her sin.
Ultimately, then, there is no conflict to reconcile.  Jesus did not make any claim conflicting with the Law, did not behave contrary to the Law, nor did he even leave members of the crowd in the position of having violated the law in this case.

" Perhaps by Law she was deserving of death, but Jesus made the crowd confront the fact that so too were all of them". I wouldn't think everyone in the crowd had broken a Law deserving of death.

There is a very big difference between these stories both morally and legally.
In numbers 15, it is the LORD who orders the execution.  In John 8 it is the lynch mob who wants to stone the woman - which was quite illegal under Torah law.
This was not the only illegal part of their accusation:

John 8:1-11 does not mention the man involved in this clear Jewish setup, was part of the plot. The woman was used and the man was very possibly one of the accusers who wanted to "frame" Jesus by trapping Him (v6).
In fact, their actions, in themselves were also illegal under Torah. If anyone saw that a crime was to be committed (v4), that person should make every effort to avoid the crime being committed. Therefore the accusers were as guilty as the woman they were accusing, especially the man involved!
It was such provisions that made it almost impossible to accuse someone of a crime worthy of the death penalty because several witness must observe the crime and such must try to prevent the crime being committed.
Under Jewish Jurisprudence, no one could be found guilty on the day they were arrested.  Then another day had to expire between the trial and the execution
In a capital crime, there had to be some one fighting for the victim - if no one could be found then the victim was let off.  in this lynch mob of John 8, no one defended the woman so the trial would be illegal
Further, the trial was not legal because it had not been legally and properly convened with witnesses called in a proper setting

[Note: a similar list illegalities could be compiled for Jesus' trial about a year later.]
Jesus was also correct that the one who had no sin was to be the first to cast stones; none did because all knew they were themselves guilty.
None of this says that the woman was innocent; only that she was obviously used to trap Jesus. Jesus approached the situation in such a way as to save both the woman and the accusers. All left chagrined (v9), but the woman left to presumably begin a new life (V11).
More than anything else - this showed the compassion, grace and forgiveness of Jesus.

Do you think the logic of "He who is without sin cast the first stone" would still apply had the scribes and Pharisees properly brought the case?

@MarkM - probably not because Jesus was, among other things, alluding to the guilty people who had illegally brought the accusation.  Indeed, it was almost impossible to get such a conviction because any witness had to try to stop the crime.

+1 One point worth noting - Jesus knew that she was guilty ("go and sin no more"), and I think the behavior of the woman shows that she understood that and recognized Him for who He is. He could have condemned her, but the law called for two witnesses.

@MarkM Almost certainly no. Jesus came to fulfill the law, not destroy it (Mt. 5:17), there's no justification to believe that He just decided here to discard the law. There was never any requirement in the law for the witnesses or judges to be sinless, but of course they couldn't be a party to the crime. The obvious conclusion is that none of them were without sin in this matter, which we can see from the fact that the woman was caught in the act but the man somehow wasn't? Dottard is almost certainly right that this was a setup, and that invalidates the witnesses.

Insightful answer, so can you point to the source of your clarifications as to the Jewish jurisprudence and the facts of the case?(maybe apart from those directly and explicitly written in Mosaic law) Thank you in advance.

@grammaplow - see https://www.bibleresearch.org/--/passover-observance/twelve-reasons-why-jesus-trial-was-illegal  and  https://www.crosswalk.com/faith/bible-study/reasons-why-the-trial-of-jesus-was-illegal.html

“... the man involved in this clear Jewish setup”
The text is equally consistent with the man having been previously executed.   Or the adulterous act having happened days ago.   Reading into the silence has little value.
“If anyone saw that a crime was to be committed (v4), that person should make every effort to avoid the crime being committed”
[citation needed]
“in this lynch mob of John 8, no one defended the woman so the trial would be illegal”
[citation needed that this was Jewish jurisprudence in the first century AD]

Jesus's new laws are love God and love your neighbor. Stoning a woman to death is not compatible with loving your neighbor. It is lawful to do good on the Sabbath, even if you have to break the Sabbath to do it. The Law is for good, not the other way around. The highest voted answer says that Jesus was right to prevent the crowd from stoning the woman to death because there weren't enough witnesses. If there were enough witnesses would Jesus have said instead, "Go ahead and stone her"? I think focusing on the Mosaic law of the situation is completely missing the point that Jesus teaches a complete revitalization of the law, and stoning people to death is not compatible with this revitalized law.

Welcome to the Biblical Hermeneutics SE. We are glad you are here. Please take a moment to take the site tour and check out what we are looking for in answers and the FAQs. We're passionate about high quality answers. Also consider going through the Help Center's sections on asking and answering questions.

"Jesus's new laws are love God and love your neighbor".   These are not new laws as these are Deut 6:5 and Lev 19:18.   What was "new" about them was to take Jesus as an example.

In each case, the message to God's people is essentially: go and sin no more. Each case brought glory to God.  The first case (man) makes clear the necessary consequences of the crime, the second (woman), the grace given thru Christ despite the crime. Jesus did not (at that time) come to judge ([Jhn 8:15 ESV] You judge according to the flesh; I judge no one.) but to save from sin.  The necessary penalty (death) was ultimately paid by Jesus, not just for the woman, but also for the man she was with, as well as all those who would have stoned her.

I will answer in two ways: first by a strict application of the Law and second by Jesus' application of Oral Torah, which allows for the expression of the Torah to evolve through rabbinical rulings.
A Strict Answer
The two examples in the OP may be reconciled by the fact that those who accused the woman failed to also bring forth the man for punishment as required in the Torah.
Deut. 22

23 If there is a young woman, a virgin who is betrothed, and a man
comes upon her in the city and lies with her, 24 you shall bring them
both out to the gate of the city and there stone them to death

There is no other Torah law stipulating stoning as a punishment for a woman who has committed adultery (although there is a law providing the death penalty for incest). Thus, those who accused her were themselves guilty of sin because they had not administered justice fairly. If they had brought forth the man for punishment, they would have been acting according to the the Law.
This answer holds that Jesus was simply upholding a strict interpretation of the Law, which required the man and the woman alike to be punished. The woman could only be condemned together with the man.
According to Oral Torah
The principle of Oral Torah (rulings of rabbinical authorities) held that the  God's Law unfolded in contemporary context. Jesus upheld this principle when he stated:
Matthew 23

2 “The scribes and the Pharisees have taken their seat on the chair of
Moses. 3 Therefore, do and observe all things whatsoever they tell
you...

The Jewish Encyclopedia explains how the Oral Torah dealt with the issue of capital punishment:

It clearly appears that there was a tendency to reduce capital
punishment to a minimum, if not to abolish it altogether. That capital
punishment was a rare occurrence in the latter days of the Jewish
commonwealth is patent from the statement in the Mishnah that a court
was stigmatized as "murderous" if it condemned to death more than one
human being in the course of seven years... Rabbis Tryphon and Akiba,
openly avowed their opposition to capital punishment, saying, "Had we
belonged to the Sanhedrin [during Judea's independence], no man would
ever have been executed." (Mak. i.
7a).

Conclusion: the two examples cited in the OP may be reconciled with reference to 1) the fact that only the woman was accused when the Law required the man to punished with her, or 2) by the liberalizing principle of Oral Torah as practiced by Jesus.

There is a big difference between what individuals may do and what the state may do.
Then and now, laws forbid killing, but the nation's armed forces may still kill enemy forces, police sometimes kill violent criminals, some states execute murderers, etc.
Similarly, God sometimes ordered an Israelite king to use his armies to destroy other nations.
In the Greek scriptures, we see this principle in Romans 13:

1 Every person is to be in subjection to the governing authorities. For there is no authority except from God, and those which exist are established by God.
2 Therefore whoever resists authority has opposed the ordinance of God; and they who have opposed will receive condemnation upon themselves.
3 For rulers are not a cause of fear for good behavior, but for evil. Do you want to have no fear of authority? Do what is good and you will have praise from the same;
4 for it is a minister of God to you for good. But if you do what is evil, be afraid; for it does not bear the sword for nothing; for it is a minister of God, an avenger who brings wrath on the one who practices evil.

The woman caught in adultery was being threatened by a mob of individual people, not by the rightful government.
But the sabbath breaker was lawfully executed by order of the Israelite government.

Nothing in the story in John makes a distinction between individuals and the modern concept of ‘the state’. Unless you think He who is without sin among you, let him be the first to throw a stone at her is saying that the state is without sin

@AviAvraham, "He who is without sin among you" addresses individuals within a mob. Would Jesus have said that to a Roman Centurion?

@RayButterworth A Roman Centurion would probably struggle to grasp the concept of sin, seeing as it wasn't a huge part of the imperial cult of Rome; if they had any concept of sin, it wouldn't have looked the same as it did in the Judaism of the time. Jesus is talking to a Jewish audience here. Ironically, while Jesus doesn't personally say this, the letter to the Romans (Romans 1:18–32) calls out the sins of pagans specifically.

@ConnieMnemonic, "sin is the transgression of the law", so would Jesus have told the Roman authorities to not arrest someone unless they had never broken the law themselves? No, for many reasons, but in particular because Christians subject themselves to the governing authorities.

@RayButterworth There's a difference between the law of God, and the law of men. The same rules can't apply. A Christian is expected to subject themselves absolutely to God, but to be subject to the governing authorities only insofar as that obedience does not conflict with obeying God. Our obedience to the state should not, for example, extend as far as genocide. The laws of men are fallible and often broken, but God's law is infallible and always perfect, so is deserving of special obedience.
